# VB.NET - How to get value of specific HTTP header?

Tags: vb.net, http

How do I check if a Header is an exact value? For example, I want to loop through IPs (I know that part) and check if a HTTP header called Content-Length with the value '2604' exists.

I've been trying but didn't succeed. any help?

Thanks in advance`!

Comment: It all depends on how you do the connection in the first place.

Comment: Please review on how to ask a question. Give us code on what you have, and specifics on what you have tried.